# Trying to use Mustasche in Tinymce preview

Tags: tinymce, mustache

As the title suggests I am trying to get Mustasche templates to work in the Tinymce preview but it does not work.

In Tinymce Plugins/Preview/plugin.js

```
previewHtml = (
                    '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
                    '<html>' +
                    '<head>' +
                    '<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/mustache.js"></script>' +
                        headHtml +
                    '</head>' +
                    '<body id="' + bodyId + '" class="mce-content-body ' + bodyClass + '"' + dirAttr + '>' +
                        editor.getContent() +
                    '</body>' +
                    '</html>'
                );
```

Stuff to preview:

```
var obj1 = { user: "John", age: 22, country: "United States" };

{{obj1.user}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is fixed now and this is how it's done:

In Tinymce Plugins/Preview/plugin.js

```
            var json = $.parseJSON($('#yourtextarea').val());
            previewHtml = (
                '<!DOCTYPE html>' +
                '<html>' +
                '<head>' +
                headHtml +
                '</head>' +
                '<body id="' + bodyId + '" class="mce-content-body ' + 
                bodyClass + '"' + dirAttr + '>' +
                Mustache.to_html(editor.getContent(),json)
                     +
                '</body>' +
                '</html>'
            );
```